# stop parent onClick when child is clicked (React or vanilla JS)

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I have a sticky bar that I would like to let users close out by having an X in the right side with `position: absolute`. However, when clicked, it also fires off the "Share to Facebook" event. How do I stop this from happening?

[image]

JS File

```
return (
    <div
      className={'ShareBar'}
      onClick={()=>console.log('sharing')}>
        <span className={'ShareCTA'}>
          {facebook.svg} Share on Facebook &trade;
          <span
            className={'CloseButton'}
            handleClick={function (e) { e.stopPropagation()/*attempted fix*/; console.log('closing'); return; }}>
              X
          </span>
        </span>
    </div>
  );
```

CSS File (it's a sass file so no semicolons and stuff

```
.ShareBar
  position fixed
  bottom 0
  z-index 9999
  display flex
  justify-content flex-end
  align-items center
  height 48px
  cursor pointer
  width 100%
  ...

  .ShareCTA
    width 100%
    position relative
    display flex
    justify-content center
    align-items center
    font-size 20px
    ...
    svg
      height 20px

  .CloseButton
    position absolute
    z-index 99999
    right 10px
    border-radius 50%
    height 40px
    width 40px
    display flex
    justify-content center
    align-items center
    ...
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`stopPropagation` will work like you have written, but the event handler for click events is called `onClick`, not `handleClick`:

```
<span
  className={'CloseButton'}
  onClick={e => e.stopPropagation()}
>
  X
</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

Wrap the Share to Facebook text in a span and attach the onClick handler to that.

You shouldn't nest an element with an onClick inside another with an onClick.

Comment: Thank you @Daniel, I agree it isn't best practice, but I would rather have the entire bar be clickable (but that circle to have the close bar on click event)